# onsubmit attribute not work

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

Hello I trying to validate my form using onsubmit attribute. But it does not work. And the funniest thing in this story - this works properly only 2 days ago. 
Form tag :

```
<form action="../actionHandlers/registrationHandler.php" onsubmit="return validateRegistrationForm()" method="post" name="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reg_form">
```

Validate function:

```
function validateRegistrationForm() {
    var errors = [];
    if (document.forms['reg_form']['username'].value.length == 0) {
        var usernameErrorMessage = localStorage.getItem('emptyLoginError');
        errors.push(usernameErrorMessage);
    }
    if (document.forms['reg_form']['password'].value.length == 0) {
        var passwordErrorMessage = localStorage.getItem('emptyPasswordError');
        errors.push(passwordErrorMessage);
    }
    if (!validateEmail(document.forms['reg_form']['email'].value)) {
        var emailErrorMessage = localStorage.getItem('emailInvalidError');
        errors.push(emailErrorMessage);
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var htmlErrors = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            htmlErrors += errors[i] + "<br />";
        }
        document.getElementById("error_message").innerHTML = htmlErrors;

        return false;
    } else {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake? Please help)

Validate email:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;

return pattern.test(email);
}
```

Inputs:

```
 <div>
            <label for="username" id="username_label"><?php echo $languageArray['USERNAME'] ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username_field" class="input_form_fields">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password"><?php echo $languageArray['PASSWORD'] ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password_field" class="input_form_fields">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email"><?php echo $languageArray['EMAIL'] ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email_field" class="input_form_fields">
        </div>
```

Comment: If the code was working previously then what has changed?

Comment: Can you provide the `validateEmail` function.

Comment: Can you also add the input fields....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I have tested it and its working:

```
<form action="../actionHandlers/registrationHandler.php" onsubmit="return validateRegistrationForm()" method="post" name="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reg_form">

<div>
    <label for="username" id="username_label"><?php echo (isset($languageArray['USERNAME']) ? $languageArray['USERNAME'] : "email"); ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username_field" class="input_form_fields">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="password"><?php echo (isset($languageArray['PASSWORD']) ? $languageArray['PASSWORD'] : "email"); ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password_field" class="input_form_fields">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="email"><?php echo (isset($languageArray['EMAIL']) ? $languageArray['EMAIL'] : "email"); ?></label><span id="required_mark">*</span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_field" class="input_form_fields">
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;

    return pattern.test(email);
}


function validateRegistrationForm(e) {
    var errors = [];
    if (document.forms['reg_form']['username'].value.length == 0) {
        var usernameErrorMessage =  localStorage.getItem('emptyLoginError') ? localStorage.getItem('emptyLoginError') : "username error";
        errors.push(usernameErrorMessage);
    }
    if (document.forms['reg_form']['password'].value.length == 0) {
        var passwordErrorMessage = localStorage.getItem('emptyPasswordError') ? localStorage.getItem('emptyPasswordError') : "password error";
        errors.push(passwordErrorMessage);
    }
    if (!validateEmail(document.forms['reg_form']['email'].value)) {
        var emailErrorMessage = localStorage.getItem('emailInvalidError') ? localStorage.getItem('emailInvalidError') : "email error";
        errors.push(emailErrorMessage);
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var htmlErrors = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            htmlErrors += errors[i] + "<br />";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("error_message")){

            document.getElementById("error_message").innerHTML = htmlErrors;
        }
        return false;
    } else {

        return true;
    }
}
```

The way I see it the problem were caused by any of the following:

1. `localStorage.getItem` notice that you don't even check to see if the key exists.
2. `echo $languageArray['PASSWORD']` again there is no check at all, **although** I'm sure its not php error but its good to check before you echo.
3. `document.getElementById("error_message")`, well you use the `innerHTML` but the `document.getElementById` my return `undefined`.

**Conclusion:**

The code should work.

**But:**

You say it worked before, I'm thinking you have touched the html in one way or another, if its not the html check the **localStorage** keys.

Comment: yes code works, i find my problem. its in `window.location.reload()`. thats all...

Comment: @excluded_once I'm glad you did.